# Insert sound/audio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, audio

I have a database containing a `ListView` and a picture, I want to include in each of each voice data. I've tried but I got a lot of errors. The following are my java and xml.

[image]

Database.java

```
package com.example.database;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    final static String DB_NAME = "db_tum_obat";
public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tum(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nama TEXT, nama_latin TEXT, khasiat TEXT, img BLOB, img2 BLOB)";
    db.execSQL(sql);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("_id", "1");
    values.put("nama", "Jarak Pagar");
    values.put("nama_latin", "Jatropha curcas Linn.");
    values.put("khasiat",
            "ketombe, lemah saraf, menghitamkan rambut, rambut rontok, rematik");
    values.put("img", R.drawable.im31);
    values.put("img2", R.drawable.home);// im31 nama file gambar dengan
                                        // ukuran 80 x 80 pixel yang ada di
                                        // folder res/drawable pada project
    db.insert("tum", "_id", values);

    values.put("_id", "2");
    values.put("nama", "Kumis Kucing");
    values.put("nama_latin", "Orthosipon aristatus (B1) Miq.");
    values.put("khasiat",
            "ketombe, lemah saraf, menghitamkan rambut, rambut rontok, rematik");
    values.put("img", R.drawable.im32);
    values.put("img2", R.drawable.keluar1);// im32 nama file gambar dengan
                                        // ukuran 80 x 80 pixel yang ada di
                                        // folder res/drawable pada project
    db.insert("tum", "_id", values);

    values.put("_id", "3");
    values.put("nama", "Lidah Buaya");
    values.put("nama_latin", "Aloe Verra Linn.");
    values.put("khasiat",
            "ketombe, lemah saraf, menghitamkan rambut, rambut rontok, rematik");
    values.put("img", R.drawable.im33);
    values.put("img2", R.drawable.home);// im33 nama file gambar dengan
                                        // ukuran 80 x 80 pixel yang ada di
                                        // folder res/drawable pada project
    db.insert("tum", "_id", values);

    values.put("_id", "4");
    values.put("nama", "Pandan Wangi");
    values.put("nama_latin", "Pandanus amryllifolius Roxb");
    values.put("khasiat",
            "ketombe, lemah saraf, menghitamkan rambut, rambut rontok, rematik");
    values.put("img", R.drawable.im34);
    values.put("img2", R.drawable.keluar1);// im34 nama file gambar dengan
                                        // ukuran 80 x 80 pixel yang ada di
                                        // folder res/drawable pada project
    db.insert("tum", "_id", values);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tum");
    onCreate(db);

}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.database;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected ListView lv;
protected ListAdapter adapter;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor cursor;
EditText et_db;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = (new Database(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    et_db = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tum ORDER BY nama ASC", null);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.isi_lv, cursor,
                new String[] { "nama", "nama_latin", "img" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.tv_nama, R.id.tv_penyebab, R.id.imV });
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                detail(position);

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void search_db(View v) {
    String edit_db = et_db.getText().toString();
    if (!edit_db.equals("")) {
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tum WHERE nama LIKE ?",
                    new String[] { "%" + edit_db + "%" });
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.isi_lv,
                    cursor, new String[] { "nama", "nama_latin", "img" },
                    new int[] { R.id.tv_nama, R.id.tv_penyebab, R.id.imV });
            if (adapter.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Tidak ditemukan data dengan kata kunci " + edit_db
                                + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tum ORDER BY nama ASC",
                    null);
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.isi_lv,
                    cursor, new String[] { "nama", "nama_latin", "img" },
                    new int[] { R.id.tv_nama, R.id.tv_penyebab, R.id.imV });
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void detail(int position) {
    int im2 = 0;
    String _id = "";
    String nama = "";
    String latin = "";
    String khasiat = "";
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        im2 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("img2"));
        nama = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nama"));
        latin = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nama_latin"));
        khasiat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("khasiat"));
    }

    Intent iIntent = new Intent(this, DetailTum.class);
    iIntent.putExtra("dataIM2", im2);
    iIntent.putExtra("dataNama", nama);
    iIntent.putExtra("dataLatin", latin);
    iIntent.putExtra("dataKhasiat", khasiat);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, iIntent);
    startActivityForResult(iIntent, 99);
}

 }
```

DetailTum.java

```
package com.example.database;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DetailTum extends Activity {
ImageView Im2;
TextView tv_nama, tv_latin, tv_khasiat, id, namaIm;
Gallery gallery;
ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
Integer[] imageIDs = new Integer[3];
int msg_im2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail);

    Intent iIdentifikasi = getIntent();
    msg_im2 = iIdentifikasi.getIntExtra("dataIM2", 0);
    String msg_nama = iIdentifikasi.getStringExtra("dataNama");
    String msg_latin = iIdentifikasi.getStringExtra("dataLatin");
    String msg_khasiat = iIdentifikasi.getStringExtra("dataKhasiat");
    Im2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_detail2);
    tv_nama = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNama);
    tv_latin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatin);
    tv_khasiat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvKhasiat);
    Im2.setImageResource(msg_im2);
    tv_nama.setText(msg_nama);
    tv_latin.setText(msg_latin);
    tv_khasiat.setText(msg_khasiat);
}
  }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFF567"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="search_db"
    android:text="Search" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et" >
</ListView>
```

isi_lv.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_nama"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imV"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="10pt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_penyebab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_nama"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_nama"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFF567"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_detail2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nama" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=":" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNama"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nama Latin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=":" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLatin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Khasiat" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=":" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvKhasiat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of trying to store the sound in a database, instead try storing the path to the sound file. Then, store the sound file in an accessible place.

Comment: I've tried and did not succeed

Comment: What do you mean by "did not succeed?"  Telthien has pointed you in the right direction.  Your question has less to do with storing sound data in SQLite and more to do with how to store and access sound files properly.  Don't rely on a kludge when you haven't fully explored the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to save the path, do what Telthien said.

If you want to save the file as a whole,You can save the data as BLOB type. http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html